# Typescript issue with onClick with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm using a custom `Icon` component like so:

```
<Icon onClick={() => {}} />
```

However, `TypeScript` underlines the `Icon` and gives the following message, which I can't quite figure out:

```
Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<Props, "className" | "name"> & Partial<Pick<Props, never>>, "className" | "name"> & { theme?: any; } & { as?: "symbol" | "object" | ... 174 more ... | undefined; }'.ts(2322)
```

My `Icon` component is a `styled-component` as seen below:

```
interface Props {
  name: string
  className?: string
}

const Icon = styled(({name, className, ...props}: Props) => <i className={`material-icons ${className}`} {...props}>{name}</i>)``
```

I was able to silence `TypeScript` by adding the following to `Icon`'s interface declaration to allow any property:

```
[x: string]: any
```

but it feels like it's a hack, and I'd like to understand the issue and find a proper solution.

Interestingly, if I use the same way a custom `Button` component, I don't get the error:

```
<Button onClick={() => {}} />

const Button = styled.button``
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your prop definition for `Icon` tells typescript, that only `name` and `className` are valid properties.

```js
interface Props {
  name: string
  className?: string
}
```

If you also want allow `onClick` you have to add it:

```js
interface Props {
  name: string;
  className?: string;
  onClick: (e: Event) => void;
}
```

or if you want to allow all properties, which are valid for `<i>` you use the following:

```js
interface Props extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
  name: string
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on extending `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>`, this is exactly what I needed!